# React-Router: Process of server request with Client-Side Routing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to understand to client-side routing works. But I still got a hard time to imagine how it works.

Let's say I've got some code like this (for example):

```
<Router>
    <Route path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/users" component={Users} />
    <Route path="/widgets" component={Widgets} />
</Router>
```

How is the process?

Are the code of the components are all downloaded from the webserver at once when I request index.html? Then everything is managed with JavaScript on the client-side and no further requests are needed?

Let's say the URL ' example.com/#/users ' is called. As a consequence some part of the side is exchanged with the content of Users-component?

Or are the components requested when needed? Lazy loaded so to speak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process:
The route you described imports all components handling routes, so they are all available in resulting bundle. Router matches path and renders these components accordingly (on `/` renders `Home`, on `/users` renders `Users` and so on). They are not lazy loaded because they are already included in route definition.

To have components lazy loaded you will have to use [dynamic routing](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/DynamicRouting.md)

Comment: Thanks a lot. From "Dynamic Routing": "The primary concern for large apps is the amount of JavaScript required to boot the app." Exact that concern was what made me thinking: Does it really load down ALL at once? What is if it is a large app? So obviously it's indeed a general issue.